# Protect sensitive information from Site Collection Admins

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-documents

Is there a way to prevent a SharePoint site collection administrator from viewing the contents of a file without leaving a trail?

I’m one of the farm administrators as well as one of the site collection administrators and we are developing an InfoPath form that will contain sensitive information. It would be nice if we could assure the form owners that nobody, including the site admins, would be able to access the sensitive information leaving a trail. It’s okay if the admins have to take ownership of the file to view it because that would leave a trail.

Answer (score 2):

you can enable auditing on the list that holds the file. That way you can keep a record of who accesses which file at what time etc.

Comment: Just adding the link to show how to turn on auditing:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101000051033.aspx

Comment: Being able to audit who opens the files is more of a backup requirement. I was asked to see if we can protect the files in a way that is similar to the private content in a person’s MySite. The only way I know for sys admins to access private MySite content is to take ownership of the MySite site collection, which would be hard to do by accident.

Comment: Well, you could log in to the site as using the app pool account, which security wise sits one level above the site admin. When logged in using that account remove the permissions on hte list for all users except the system account. Not sure if this will work but it should. To acces the list thorugh code just use RunWithElevatedPrivileges.